# Synching Netsuite and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, netsuite, email-validation, membership

I want to be able to export a list of members from Netsuite and store their email domains in the backend of Wordpress. I am setting up a separate member portal through wufoo/Wordpress so that when a potential new member goes to register through our Wordpress site, the site automatically searches through the email addresses on file and work out whether that person is eligible to sign up for membership.

Hope this make sense?

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it sounds possible but this question seems to broad for one answer to be sufficient. maybe try it step by step and ask more specific questions when you are stuck?

Comment: OK. How do I import a list of contacts from Netsuite to my Wordpress site?

Answer (score 0):

Enable REST in Wordpress Jetpack and call the rest API using nlapiRequestURL.